# Rails find method is it safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know if it is safe to use this:

```
@company = Company.find(params[:company_ids])
```

Is it safe against SQL injections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [Section 8.2.4 of the official Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures), the `Model.find(id)` method automatically escapes the input, so it's safe.